# Jquery slide banner start close

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to add a sliding banner at the bottom of the page, but the banner is starting opened instead of closed. How can I make it start close?

**[JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/v6sg8f71/)**

```
$(function() {
    var open = false;
    $('#footerSlideButton').click(function() {
        if(open === false) {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '300px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'bottom left');
            open = true;
        } else {
            $('#footerSlideContent').animate({ height: '0px' });
            $(this).css('backgroundPosition', 'top left');
            open = false;
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: I also realized that the banner only closes on the second attemp of clicking on the close button/bar

Comment: ok the 2 click thing I solved by changing the "false" on the second line to "true". I dont know what that does but its now working by only 1 click. but the start close problem I dont know how to fix it.. :S I'm newbie in jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="footerSlideContent" style="height: 300px;">
```

You have inline style which overwrite your css rule. Remove that.